# If $7$ is the first digit of $2^n$, what is the first digit of $5^n$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Let $2^n = 7\cdot 10^x + p$ and $5^n = a\cdot 10^y + r$

And now what?

(We're in base $10$)

Comment: It would seem that the answer is $1$, although I have yet to either prove or disprove it. I've tested it for $n = 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96, 149, 159, 169, 179, 189$ and they all give $a = 1$.

Comment: Can you give an example for such $n$, by the way?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $n=46$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By assumption, we can write $2^n=x\cdot 10^m$ with $7\le x<8$.
Also, we can write $5^n=y\cdot 10^k$ with $1\le y<10$.
Then $10^n=2^n5^n=xy10^{m+k}$, so $xy$ must be a power of $10$.
If $y\ge 2$, we obtain $14\le xy<80$, no power of ten. Therefore $1\le y<2$, i.e. the leading digit of $5^n$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$10^n=2^n*5^n.$
$$10/7=1,.....$$
Thats why answer is $1$